# flexslider resizing issue for iphone/ipad

Tags: resize, flexslider

I've implemented flexslider before, but this time it is not resizing when I view it in i-phone or i-pad. Also its not working when I'm resizing my browser window.
Please suggest any workarounds..
For now I've made it work by adding media query in flexslider.css file.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it, the problem was because of Bootstrap framework. Elements with classname "span1/2/3.." in bootstrap don't resize beyond a fix browser width, even when using fluid structure. Because of that my flexslider div was not getting resized.

I just changed the fixed with of .span class from "px" to "%" and it started working.